# Can I git diff a subset of files between two branches

Tags: git

git diff branch..branch1 will generate all the difference between two branches.

is there a way to diff a given list of files?

'git diff branch..branch1 filename' can do it for just one file, what if I want to supply a list of files?

Comment: Do you mean you have a file with a list of filenames?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
git diff branch..branch1 -- file1 file2
```

So if you have a filelist, you can use a shell expansion (in bash, for example) to enumerate the contents of your filelist.

```
> cat filelist
file1
file2
> echo $(cat filelist)
file1 file2
> git diff branch..branch1 -- $(cat filelist)
```

where the final command should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-- <path> <path>` and so on to [git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob patterns.  For instance, if you have the following folder structure

```
  -project
    -client
      -...more folders
    -server
      -...more folders
```

from the project folder you could run the following commmand:

```
git diff client/**
```

which would give you a diff of everything in the client folder and subfolders, but ignore the server folders.